# Rearrange Header and Data of different versions of Text file based on a Master File

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I want to re-arrange the data (Header and Detail) in multiple pipe delimited text files, in the Field|Order specified in a reference master file and create a single output file, using shell script. I have the code below, but not working as expected. The while loop is getting the order of the column from master, and rearranging. But need to account for below functionality. **Looking for a Solution in Shell Script/awk**.

There could be columns missing or new columns in the input files, when compared to the Reference master file.
The order in the Reference master file could change in future and columns could be added to or deleted from any position.
Accept multiple input files.

Sample Input file A:

```
Name|Amount|Vehicle|City|Visits|Indicator

Jack|123.22|Volkswagen|Altamonte|1|Y

Sam|23.1|Audi||3|N

|21.4|Ford|NewYork||Y
```

Sample Input file B:

```
Suffix|Name|Visits|Vehicle|State|Indicator|City|Gender

Mr|Jack|1|Volkswagen|NJ|Y|Hoboken|M

Mr|Rob|6|Buick||N|Stamford|
```

Reference Master File:

State|1

City|2

Vehicle|3

Gender|4

Name|5

Amount|6

Output File:

```
State|City|Vehicle|Gender|Name|Amount

|Altamonte|Volkswagen||Jack|123.22

||Audi||Sam|23.1

|NewYork|Ford|||21.4

NJ|Hoboken|Volkswagen|M|Jack|

|Stamford|Buick||Rob|
```

Shell script:

```
/*Comment::Reads the input column names and assign number based on order for*/
/*Comment::each column in the input file.*/
cat infile.out | head -1 | tr -s '|' '\n' | cat -n > infile_tmp.out
rm -f final.out

/*Comment:compare the master file column names with input file column names and 
/*Comment:get the column number from master file*/ 
while read line; do 
touch final.out
vChkClmn=`echo $line | cut -d "|" -f1`
vMasterClm=`grep -i $vChkClmn infile_tmp.out | cut -d " " -f1`
echo "$vMasterClm" >> final.out
done < master_file.out

rm -f final_master_list.out
echo `cat final.out` | sed 's/[^ ]* */\$&/g' | sed 's/ /\,/g' > final_master_list.out
vOrder=`cat final_master_list.out`
echo "Value of order is $vOrder"
awk -F\| '{print '$vOrder'}' OFS=\| infile.out
```

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $master = shift;
open(M,"<","$master") || die "couldn't open $master:$!\n";
chomp(my @master = split(/\|/,<M>));
close(M);

print join("|",@master),"\n";

my @fields=();
while (<>) {
  if ($. == 1) {
    chomp(@fields = split /\|/);
    next;
  };

  chomp(my @row = split/\|/);
  my @out = ();

  foreach my $m (@master) {
    my $o='';
    for (my $i=0; $i < $#row; $i++) {
      if ($fields[$i] eq $m) {
        $o = $row[$i];
      };
    }
    push @out, $o;
  };

  print join("|",@out),"\n";
} continue {
    close ARGV if eof; # reset the line counter after each input file
}
```

This reads in the reference master file (which **must** be the first argument on the command line) and splits it into an array (@master) holding the field names.

After that, it reads all remaining filename arguments and:

- if it is the first line of a file, get the field headers by splitting the line into array `@fields`
- otherwise, split the line into array `@row`, and loop though both @master and  each element of `@row`.   When the field **name** of a row element matches an element in @master, add that field's **value** to the output array (@out), otherwise add the empty string.
- print the `@out` array joined by `|` characters.
- the `@out` array is reset to empty on every input line.

Save it as, e.g., `rearrange.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x rearrange.pl` and run it as:

```
$ ./rearrange.pl master.txt input1.txt input2.txt 
State|City|Vehicle|Gender|Name|Amount
|Altamonte|Volkswagen||Jack|123.22
||Audi||Sam|23.1
|NewYork|Ford|||21.4
NJ|Hoboken|Volkswagen||Jack|
|Stamford|Buick||Rob|
```

Note: this is not limited to just two input files.  It can process any number of input files at a time.  There are only two restrictions:

1. The master reference file (e.g. `master.txt`) **MUST** be the first argument on the command line.
2. There must be at least one input file **or** the input file must be piped into the script.

   Note: only one input file can be **piped** - the script has no way of knowing which lines are header lines and which are data lines if more than one file is piped in.

Comment: FYI you could re-implement this algorithm in bash (or some other sh with arrays) if you really insisted on doing so.   I wouldn't recommend it. At all.  shell is not a good language for processing text. It's a good language for wrapping and automating the execution of other programs.    `awk` would be a decent alternative to perl, but you'd have to write your own `join()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution in Perl. I only had to change to "$i <= $#row" and it worked. I would have to use awk/shell and re-write this due to special constraints at our end. I got something as below. It is numbering the columns in the input file based on the column number in the master file, but no re-arranging finally. And it does not account for the scenario of missing and new columns in the source file.

Comment: <code>
cat infile.out | head -1 | tr -s '|' '\n' | cat -n > infile_tmp.out
rm -f final.out
while read line; do 
touch final.out
vChkClmn=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f2`
vMasterClm=`grep -i $vChkClmn master_file.out | cut -d "|" -f2`
echo "$vMasterClm" >> final.out
done < infile_tmp.out
rm -f final_master_list.out
echo `cat final.out` | sed 's/[^ ]* */\$&/g' | sed 's/ /\,/g' > final_master_list.out
vOrder=`cat final_master_list.out`
echo "Value of order is $vOrder"
awk -F\| '{print '$vOrder'}' OFS=\| infile.out </code>

Comment: Input File: first_name|last_name|dob|strt_dt|clm_id
Sam|Clark|03221993|05062010|a342d
Andrew|John|10181997|08112017|a342d

Comment: Master File: dob|1
clm_id|2
last_name|3
first_name|4
strt_dt|5

Comment: there's no need for `<=`, perl arrays start from zero, so $i needs to iterate from 0 to $#row - 1. hence the < rather than <=.

Comment: code fragments in comments are unreadable, but it looks like you're trying to do this in a mix of shell and awk.  just re-implement the whole thing in awk.   if you want anyone to look at your example code then edit your **question** and add both the code and sample output

Comment: Thank you. I will edit the question with the script and file.